# how to create an item container that rotates automatically and stops on mouse hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
       <div class="part-1 content">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <img src="images/sc/part-1-alt.png" class="img-responsive" alt="a" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Donec id elit non mi porta loreta et">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <img src="images/sc/part-2.png" class="img-responsive" alt="a" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Donec id elit non mi porta loreta et">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <img src="images/sc/part-3.png" class="img-responsive" alt="a" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Donec id elit non mi porta loreta et">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <img src="images/sc/part-4.png" class="img-responsive" alt="a" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Donec id elit non mi porta loreta et">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <img src="images/sc/part-5.png" class="img-responsive" alt="a" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Donec id elit non mi porta loreta et">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <img src="images/sc/part-6-alt.png" class="img-responsive" alt="a" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Donec id elit non mi porta loreta et">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is the element i would want to behave so. What i want is to make it look like a band you see on the news that moves and stop when i hover the mouse over it. I am using bootstrap 3, if it could be done within its carousel that would be great. I did some search prior to asking this but i really couldn't find anything relevant, so excuse me if this is actually a duplicate of another differently worded question

Answer (score 0):

Oh it's called **infinite-loop** carousel and there is an option that you can specify what event you want to trigger a pause: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#carousel.

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 2000,
  pause: 'hover' 
 /*Pauses the cycling of the carousel on mouseenter 
 and resumes the cycling of the carousel on mouseleave. */
})
```

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0v7ddB_9cGc i want it to rotate like the weather text bar in this video rotates, if you know what i mean

Comment: I see. Rotate has a lot of meaning when it comes to web design and development, you should be more specific. This is one is called a **loop** carousel. I've updated my answer pls check. I just watched RoboCop a while ago :P.

Comment: thanks for your update.i hope you enjoyed your movie. however, the question is how would i make the column items cycle like that continuously?